# Count the total number of nodes connected via particular type of relationship to another node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two types of nodes in my db "Organisation" and "User" and these are connected as:

```
(u : User)-[:TEAMMEMBER_OF | BOARDMEMBER_OF | FOUNDER_OF]->(o : Organisation)
```

So a user can be a teammember, boardmember or a founder. Now I have to return all of the organisations which have less than 5 members in total.  It may be possible than an organisation doesn't have any member. To count the number of members I wrote a query like this

```
Match (o : Organisation) 
Optional Match (o)<-[r:TEAMMEMBER_OF | BOARDMEMBER_OF | FOUNDER_OF]-(u : User) 
return o, cnt
```

but it is not giving me correct count of members for each organisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be aware of a fine difference between `count(*)` and `count(x)`. The latter counts the number of non null values of x whereas the former gives the number of rows - including nulls.

```
match (o:Organisation) 
optional match (o)<-[r:TEAMMEMBER_OF|:BOARDMEMBER_OF|:FOUNDER_OF]-(u:User) 
with o, count(u) as cnt // of Org has no members we get 0
where cnt < 5
return o, cnt
```